# Qt - debug on Android device

Tags: android, qt

I'm developing application on Qt Creator. I've debugged my application on Android by toast message or dialog or something like that.Is there anyway to debugging Qt on Android device and showing breakpoints in Qt Creator?

Comment: Have you tried start for debugging option? I've developed an app for Android using Qt/QML a year ago, and I remember that I had no problems with debuggin on device.

Comment: Theres no official alternative to Android Toasts on Qt, unless you build the class out yourself. See [QDebug](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) for outputting debug messages to the log.